# How to create a pipe in angular to always return two decimal points even with a whole number

Tags: angular

I wanted to create a pipe such that it returns number with only 2 decimal places without rounding off. Also It should return `.00` if its a whole number.

**I tried:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncateNumber',
})
export class TruncateNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): string {
    let fixed = 2;
    fixed = fixed || 0;
    fixed = Math.pow(10, fixed);
    if (typeof fixed === 'string') {
      return '';
    }
    return (Math.floor(value * fixed) / fixed).toString();
  }
}
```

**Sample cases:**

1. 123.4567 = 123.45 // working
2. 123 = 123.00 // not working

Please help.

Comment: return Number(value).toFixed(2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add `.toFixed(2)` to your return

This will fix your number to 2 decimal places.

Add this transform function to your pipe and you should have the wanted functionality.

```js
/*
 * Formats a number with a set of digits without rounding.
 * Takes an digits argument that defaults to 2.
 * Usage:
 *   value | truncateNumber:digits
 * Example:
 *   {{ 123 | truncateNumber:3 }}
 *   formats to: 123.000
 *   {{ 123.4567 | truncateNumber }}
 *   formats to: 123.45
*/

const transform = (value, digits = 2) => {
  const fixed = Math.pow(10, digits);
  return (Math.floor(value * fixed) / fixed).toFixed(digits).toString();
}

console.log('123.4567 ->', transform(123.4567));
console.log('123      ->', transform(123));

console.log('123      ->', transform(123, 1));
```

#### Full angular code, not runnable - added for copy paste.

```js
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncateNumber',
})
export class TruncateNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  const transform = (value, digits = 2) => {
    const fixed = Math.pow(10, digits);
    return (Math.floor(value * fixed) / fixed).toFixed(digits).toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: let fixed = 2;
fixed = fixed || 0;

omgosh)))